# Como saber si ya existe una tabla temporal

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un SP en el cual creo una tabla temporal de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT *
INTO #TABLA_AR
FROM TRABAJADOR
WHERE AREA IN (3,5,9,15)
```

El SP tiene varios procesos y si falla en algun proceso despues de crear la tabla temporal, al momento de corregir el error y ejecutarlo falla debido a que la tabla temporal ya existe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todas las tablas temporales se guardan en la base de datos llamada `tempdb`, por lo que deberías de buscar ahí tu tabla temporal antes de intentar crearla:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLA_AR') IS NULL
BEGIN
print 'no existe'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
print 'existe'
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Usa esto antes de crear tu tabla temporal

```
if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TABLA_AR','U')) is not null
    drop table #TABLA_AR
```

Este fragmento valida si ya existe la tabla temporal. Si existe la elimina, de esta forma podrías ejecutar el resto del código

Comment: +1 por incluir el parámetro `'U'`.

Answer (score 2):

hola creo que seria asi:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLA_AR') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TABLA_AR
```

colocas esta instrucción en tu SP y puedes volver a crearla, es a lo que te refieres?